# ntbackup fails to save to NAS under windows sbs 2003

Tags: windows, backup, network-attached-storage, windows-sbs-2003, ntbackup

I created a backup plan to backup to a NAS via UNC (\\192.168.x.y\backup\pdc) on our Windows 2003 SBS, which stops after 1 sec with this error: *"The operation was not performed because the specified media cannot be found."*

I think this has something to do with the user running the ntbackup script itself. When I execute the ntbackup command in my administrator commandline, it works as it should. If the backup routine kicks in (it is listed in the scheduled tasks list, where one can i.e. run it manually), it does not work. I read something about a SBS Backup User, who executes the command.

How can I change that or how can I give that particular user the right (aka provide credentials) to access the NAS?

Comment: What kind of NAS are you using? Is it Windows-based or something else?

Comment: Should be one of those: INTEL SS4000E. The folder i want to access is marked as Windows (Samba) share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It maybe had something to do with a recent change to the administrative account's password.

I deleted all "planned tasks" related to the backup process, and recreated them with the "add planned task" wizard. By using the backup wizard then provided, i was able to set up everything as i wanted it through the ntbackup interface, and now have also the full command ("ntbackup.exe ...") in the tasklist.
Having set the *run as* stuff correctly, **this now works fine** - and the **sbs recovery tools work too**.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to specify the user account when you schedule the backup. Either in the advanced settings of ntbackup, or in task scheduler.

Comment: Tried this, but then I learned that the task itself runs bkprunner.exe, which then invokes ntbackup.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the SBS backup wizard. Writing your own script to run NTBackup is easy, and you get to choose how the scheduled job is run. There are lots of walkthroughs on scripting NTBackup, or I can post a script here. It's easier than you think. The scripts around on the web tend to look complicated, but only because they do lots of extra cunning stuff.

JR

Comment: I have no problem with not using the wizard, but being new to that sbs stuff I was just curious if I'd loose that restore functions it offers if I don't do the backups with it.

Comment: Hi Kartsen, as you've spotted, the SBS wizard just uses NTBackup and the restores are just NTBackup restores. The wizard is pretty good at simplifying what can be some messy scripting, but as you've found it has it's limitations. The nice thing about scheduling a script is you can have your script do things like "dir \\192.168.x.y\backup\pdc 1>>log.txt 2>>&1" to help diagnose errors (in this case presumably you'll get an "access denied" error.

Comment: Lot's of people have not used the SBS integrated tools and lived to regret it. Standard advice from the SBS experts is to always use the integrated tools. SBS is a difficult balancing act between a lot of potentially conflicting technologies and there are lots of subtle interactions. The SBS wizards and integrated tools help you keep things set up within the very narrow constraints of what will work and what is supported. It is an unwise admin who strays outside that framework.

Comment: @Tim Long: Yes, this was my initial thought, too. But do you have any advice on the actual topic? :)

Comment: Hi Tim, I agree up to a point, and that point is the backup. I look after over a hundred SB2003 installations (and two SBS 2008s) so I have been burned by everything in SBS that can burn you, and I'd agree that as far as possible you should use the SBS tools provided by MS. However I would always roll my own backup.